# Using SLURM arrays to divide a R script into sub-jobs?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, slurm

I have a R script I would like to divide into several jobs, each one on a node of the cluster.

```
res<-foreach(i = seq_len(nrow(combs))) %dopar% {
 G1 <- split[[combs[i,1]]]
 G2 <- split[[combs[i,2]]]
 bind <- cbind(data[,G1], data[,G2])
 rho.i <- cor_rho(bind)     #the function cor_rho I created  
 }
```

This is the code I would like to parallelize. I divide a big matrix into submatrices, and I compute the correlations between each combination of these submatrices :

submatrix 1 vs submatrix 2         : node 1
 submatrix 1 vs submatrix 3         : node 2 
   etc.

I tried something like this (if I have 10 combinations to compute for example) , I don't show you the whole SLURM code :

```
#SBATCH --array=1-10

Rscript my_R_script > my_output
```

It creates 10 arrays, but I wonder if each array computes one computation. In other words, if one array = one node = one comparison between two submatrices?

Bests

Edit :

This is how `combs` looks like :

```
> combs
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    1    4
 [4,]    1    5
 [5,]    2    3
 [6,]    2    4
 [7,]    2    5
 [8,]    3    4
 [9,]    3    5
[10,]    4    5


combs <- combs[opt$subset,] #SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

#The loop which computes each combination

res <- foreach(i = seq_len(nrow(combs))) %dopar% {
 G1 <- split[[combs[i,1]]]
 G2 <- split[[combs[i,2]]]
 dat.i <- cbind(data[,G1], data[,G2])
 rho <- cor_rho(dat.i)
}

#I fill my final matrix

resMAT <- matrix(0, ncol(data), ncol(data))

for(i in 1:nrow(combs)){
 batch1 <- split[[combs[i,1]]]
 batch2 <- split[[combs[i,2]]]
 patch.i <- c(batch1, batch2)
 resMAT[patch.i, patch.i] <- res[[i]]
}
```

Then, my SLURM code :

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o slurmjob-%A-%a.out
#SBATCH --job-name=parallel_nodes
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --time=1-00:00:00
#SBATCH --array=1-10

#Set up whatever package we need to run with

module load gcc/8.1.0 openblas/0.3.3 R

# SET UP DIRECTORIES

OUTPUT="$HOME"/PROJET_M2/data/$(date +"%Y%m%d")_parallel_nodes
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT"

echo $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

subset=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID))

Rscript my_R_code > "$OUTPUT"/"$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"
```

I execute this script with :

```
sbatch --partition normal --array 1-10 RHO_COR.sh
```

And I get a message error :

```
Error in combs[i, 1] : index out of bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

*I wonder if each array computes one computation.*

Each run of the array can run one (or potentially multiple scripts).

*In other words, if one array = one node = one comparison between two submatrices?*

Yes, you can do it like this. Though you probably want to specify which one of the comparisons.

*I really don't know how I could specify which comparison I need to compute on which array..*

There are many ways to specify which comparison you need to compute on which array. For example you could use the array number as an argument/criterion for selection. E.g. you would have a list of *n* comparisons and a list of *n* array numbers, and based on array number you choose a corresponding comparison which has the same index/position within the list. NB: you probably also want to name your outputs appropriately - otherwise you will try to create *n* different output files all with the same name, which can cause troubles if they are in the same location.

*And I get a message error : `Error in combs[i, 1] : index out of bounds`*

This is caused by the mismatch between the dimensions of `combs` after `subset` and your indices. E.g. you are trying to access the position of combs which doesn´t exist.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191858/discussion-on-answer-by-oka-using-slurm-arrays-to-divide-a-r-script-into-sub-job).

Comment: @SamuelLiew: Thank you! I was thinking about moving to chat too, but wasn´t sure if the person who asked had access to chat function..

Comment: [Rslurm package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rslurm) was written to make these kind of tasks a little easier.

Comment: Actually, since my R script already splits my matrix into submatrices, is it really necessary to use Rslurm? I mean, could I just configure a Slurm code in order to get what I want, and not touching on my R code.

Comment: It looks like a viable option but not absolutely necessary